# creating scrollable layout in ipyvuetify

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, vuetify.js, voila

I'm using the [ipyvuetify](https://github.com/mariobuikhuizen/ipyvuetify) lib to create a nice voila layout for my jupyter notebook. I try to create a file selector inspired by [crahan/ipyfilechooser](https://github.com/crahan/ipyfilechooser).

so when the folder content is too big I want to create a scrollable list :

```py
folder_select = v.Select(items=get_parent_path('/home/prambaud'), label='folder', v_model='/home/prambaud')
file_list = v.List(
    dense=True, 
    color='grey lighten-4', 
    max_height='300px',
    flat=True,
    children=[
        v.ListItemGroup(
            active_class="border",
            children=get_items('/home/prambaud/'),
            v_model=None
        )
    ]
)
```

displaying the separately give me the exact behaviour I need : the folder selector stays on top and I can scroll in the items

```py
display(folder_select)
display(file_list)
```

[image: Capture d’écran 2020-10-07 à 10 59 28]

But I need to add them in a single widget to use them as a standalone input component so I created a layout :

```py
file_input = v.Layout(
    v_model=None,
    row=True,
    class_='pa-5',
    align_center=True,
    style_='300px',
    children=[
        v.Flex(xs12=True, children=[folder_select]),
        v.Flex(xs12=True, children=[file_list])
    ]
)
```

and max_heigth parameter is not respected any more and all the layout become scrollable instead of just the file list :

[image: Capture d’écran 2020-10-07 à 11 02 25]

it's even worse if i try to include it in a more complex layout :
[image: Capture d’écran 2020-10-07 à 11 03 38]

Is it a known bug ? Is there a way to create a scrollable Layout inside another Layout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the style `overflow: auto` to hide the overflowing content and show a scrollbar.

```py
...
max_height='300px',
style_='overflow: auto',
...
```

Comment: You had already answered this one on github I'm sorry I was too lazy to upload the anwser here. Thank you

Comment: I know, no problem. I was just answering it here so people who find the question here will also see an answer.